# how to handle viewExpirationException in jsf2

Tags: jsf-2

Im working on jsf2.

If im not using page till session timeout then page is giving the ViewExpirationException and page is broken. so how to handle this error. i was trying to redirect to ErrorPage.xhtml

```
<error-page>
     <exception-type>javax.faces.application.ViewExpiredException</exception-type>
    <location>/error.xhtml</location>
</error-page>
```

I created the error.xhtml page for display.

But im not able to see this error page. What can be my mistake.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

write this below code in

### index.xhtml

```
     <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="#{session.maxInactiveInterval};url=faces/error.xhtml" />
```

### web.xml

```
<error-page>
     <exception-type>javax.faces.application.ViewExpiredException</exception-type>
    <location>/error.xhtml</location>
</error-page>
```

create an error page and write the error message what you want to display.